# How to add HTTP BASIC authentication to a servlet in container independent way?

Tags: java, servlets

I want to protect my servlet with an HTTP Basic authentication in a container-independent way.I don't know whether it's going to be Tomcat or Glassfish or Jetty. Has to work in any container. All the links I've found so far talk about some specific container.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a filter, something in your actual servlet, or better yet, use something like spring security, read about it here: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know of any off-the-shelf filters? I'm lucky enough not to use Spring.